# Deploy 2 bundles with same Web-ContextPath in Karaf

Tags: java, apache-karaf

I want to deploy 2 different bundles, one is having all the rest services and other is having all the HTML/JSP pages in same Karaf instance. Please help on how I can do so.

(I am able to install the bundles successfully, but I am unable to access the web pages, but rest are working fine on same Web-ContextPath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, as it would also not be possible for std. Web Application Context. Your Web-ContextPath has to be unique.

What you can do is either have a shared HttpContext, or what might actually fit you better is to have either an OSGi Fragment attaching to your bundle containing the Rest Servlet, or use a web-fragment. As you're talking of a Web-ContextPath which is an attribute of a WAB you're better of with a Web Fragment. 
Only in case of using the HttpService or registering your resources as services you could go and share the HttpContext between them.

In case of Web Fragment you have a std. web.xml in your first Bundle, your second bundle would have something like the following:

```
<web-fragment xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-fragment_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
  id="module1">

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/exception.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-fragment>
```

See also the following [sample of Pax-Web](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/samples/web-fragment/war-fragment/src/main/resources/META-INF/web-fragment.xml)

For a shared HttpContext take a look at the following [sample.](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-jetty/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/itest/jetty/CrossServiceIntegrationTest.java)

Comment: So it means if I want to deploy both, I need to keep them both in same bundle as a more simple and cleaner solution? Or I can go for 2 different web context path as it is more likely that rest will be consumed by mobile apps only and HTML/JSP will be more web oriented.

Comment: Yes, you either need to have them in one WAB, or two different WABs with different Web-ContextPaths